# Usual taxi fares and things to know about transportation inside Antalya

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, turkey, taxis, antalya

I have tried to find some travel books from my local bookshop and library. They have got other cities, not Antalya. Regarding the transportation system there:

1) What are the usual taxi fares in Antalya? Including taxi from the airport to hotels (e.g. my hotel will be [Tutav Adalya Hotel](https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=36.886486,30.704556&spn=0.070709,0.15398&gl=uk&t=m&z=13) in Iskele Caddesi, near Antalya beach).

For example, when I went to Morocco, I ended up bargaining with cab drivers. If I have to do the same here, what should I know in advance?

2) Am I better off using public bus or walking by foot when travelling to nearby places?

Accommodation aside, my budget is maximum €30/day (maximum 40e).

Comment: I think it is better to split this question in two. Moreover, the second part is pretty vague. Thus, if you split the question don't forget to make it more precise ;-)

Comment: @MarcelC.   Thanks and appreciate your suggestion, but I respectfully intend to keep this as one question because of what I originally put as my reason. And the second question is totally vague. You could answer that based on the factors like budget and time. Or, it could very well be somebody who has actually done it and giving away his/her reasons for using bus/taxi/walk. Still, I am gonna edit the 2nd question and put your points :)

Comment: For me it is okay, but there are people around here who have stronger opinions on this.

Answer (score 7):

A taxi from the airport to the center costs [35 to 50 Turkish Lira (YTL)](http://www.turkeytravelplanner.com/go/med/Antalya/trans/airport_trans.html). For more information you can have a look at the [website of the Antalya Airport Taxi organization](http://www.antalyaairporttaxi.net/index.php?lng=8).

You should not bargain about prices. Neither before the trip, nor after. Taxis are metered and the driver is supposed to switch the meter on. And pay the price on the display. Take only taxis from the official taxi rank at the airport. If you think that the driver has cheated, you can call someone from the hotel when you arrive there. But don't be paranoiac. The vast majority of the Turkish taxi drivers are honest. I have taken the taxi plenty of times in Turkey, and there has never been a problem.

Just note that Morocco is not a good benchmark at all. But you will see this later on.

Regarding your second question, I think that it is too vague. It depends on where you want to go. It is difficult to set a rule. In Antalya you have a panoply of [possibilities](http://www.turkeytravelplanner.com/go/med/Antalya/trans/index.html): walk, taxi, bus, tram, dolmus. For trips nearby you may consider renting a car. Public transport will no ruin you. As an example, three rides on the AntRay tram cost 5 YTL and a bus ride costs less than 4 YTL.

Comment: Quite close to what I had in mind :) +1 for this !